# Sound not working!

Tags: 20.04, sound

I randomly noticed that my sound icon is not up at the top, and that my sound is not working. It is only on my user. I reset the user with `dconf reset -f /`, but it still doesn't do anything. I don't know what else to do. I added some images below I hope they help. [image: sound bar], [image]

Comment: image one is the sound bar at the top

Comment: image two is the sound settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only on one user, backup your user's pulse configuration and start off with an empty pulse configuration directory.

First, backup the current configuration directory:

```
cp -R ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulsebackup
```

Next, delete the files in your pulse directory:

```
rm ~/.config/pulse/*
```

Finally, log out and log back in to apply the changes.